# How can a java application identify a specific browser?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, servlets, browser

How can I identify whether the browser is Firefox or Chrome? Basically, I want an application to run only on the specific browser that is registered by a user. For this scenario, I want my application to identify the browser which the user is using, to know whether the application is permitted to run.

I am using java servlet.

I tried a the browser’s local storage, but it can be deleted with no control from my application. If local storage can be used, please let me know how.

(Yes I can get a browser info, but I want to identify a specific machine with a browser from where my application user is permitted to run the application; otherwise, I need to restrict that user from accessing my application.)

Comment: What kind of "application" ?

Comment: this thread helps you ::http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser/9851769#9851769

Comment: @shivan it is a browser management type of application

Comment: Java and Javascript isn't the same so which one do you mean?

Comment: yes, client-side or server-side ?

Comment: i will preferd a java servlet more than javascript

Comment: see basically my application is for the organizational, so i want that application can access on specific browser and machine only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fetch user-agent properties from the HTTP requeste header.

```
  String userAgent=req.getHeader("user-agent");
  String browserName = "";
  String  browserVer = "";
  if(userAgent.contains("Chrome")){ //checking if Chrome
        String substring=userAgent.substring(userAgent.indexOf("Chrome")).split(" ")[0];
        browserName=substring.split("/")[0];
        browserVer=substring.split("/")[1];
    }
    else if(userAgent.contains("Firefox")){  //Checking if Firefox
        String substring=userAgent.substring(userAgent.indexOf("Firefox")).split(" ")[0];
        browserName=substring.split("/")[0];
        browserVer=substring.split("/")[1];
    }
```

Comment: this is working but i want to configure this browser with my application so that user can only access my application through this browser only

Comment: I did not understand what you want to say?

Comment: see i want my application only run on specific browser in specific machine. If somebody try to access from different browser then i want to restrict that user

Comment: @SwapL If browser detected by the servlet is other than what you want to allow, discard the request or either show user appropriate error message..

Comment: Yes but req.getHeader("user-agent"); is enough to detect diffrent brower and diffrent machin is used that i want to know

Comment: @SwapL, Do you want to allow for particular IP address of machanine ?

Comment: not IP Address that i did already by IP address now i want it restricted upto machine and browser because my application is web base

Answer (score 2):

```
httpRequest.getHeader("user-agent")
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use the below code in servlet to know what browser is hitting your servlet.

```
String userAgent = request.getHeader("user-agent");
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code :

```
String userAgent = req.getHeader("user-agent");
UserAgent ua = UserAgent.parseUserAgentString(userAgent);
Version browserVersion = ua.getBrowserVersion();
String browserName = ua.getBrowser().toString();
int majVersion = Integer.parseInt(browserVersion.getMajorVersion());
```

Or use can easily get the browser deatils from javascript code like this - 
    Browser CodeName = navigator.appCodeName
    Browser Name = navigator.appName
    Browser Version = navigator.appVersion

Comment: is there any unique property i can get ? is there any unique property with browser ????

Comment: User-Agent value as follows: Mozilla/[version] ([system and browser information]) [platform] ([platform details]) [extensions]0

Comment: Copy this script into your JavaScript files. It works immediately, and you can query three properties of the BrowserDetect object:       
    Browser name: BrowserDetect.browser
    Browser version: BrowserDetect.version
    OS name: BrowserDetect.OS

Comment: @LalitHaryani this all are the unique property of browser??? if i save this data then i can trigger where my application run and where not???

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet
{  
   @Override
   public void doGet(final HttpServletRequest aRequest,   
                     final HttpServletResponse aResponse) throws ServletException, IOException
   {  
       final String agent = aRequest.getHeader("user-agent");
       // agent will looks like  
       // Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0
       // Mozilla/2.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2)
       // Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36
       // etc.
   }
}
```

Comment: from user-agent  can i restrict application login also ? means suppose my application is only allowed to login with one machine and one browser....

Comment: @SwapL what means `application login`? Is it login entered by user in `form input`?

Comment: @SwapL client: `<input name="someName"/>` server: `aRequest.getParameter("someName")`